# Split string in bash

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, shell

I'm trying to monitor some hung threads in an application server and I got this line.
`[5/30/16 11:31:18:501 CDT] 00000655 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0606W: Thread "MessageListenerThreadPool : 38" (00000655) was previously reported to be hung but has completed.  It was active for approximately 964450 milliseconds.  There is/are 0 thread(s) in total in the server that still may be hung.`

I need to obtain the 0 in "There is/are 0 thread(s)".
I tried to split it using cut, but everything was a mess. I also tried to use a delimiter, but the string is too long. 
How can I split it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to capture the number between "There is/are " and " thread" and remove everything else, like this:

```
sed 's/.*There is\/are \([0-9]\+\) thread.*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -nr 's/.*are ([0-9]+) thread.*/\1/p' file
```

---

```
-r, --regexp-extended
use extended regular expressions in the script.

-n, --quiet, --silent
suppress automatic printing of pattern space
```